# What are the main issues addressed by New Zealand's recent rocket legislation?

Tags: law, space-agencies

The Channel News Asia article [New Zealand launches into space race with 3D-printed rocket](http://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/technology/new-zealand-launches-into-space-race-with-3d-printed-rocket-8882210) says:

> New Zealand has created new rocket legislation and set up a space agency in anticipation of becoming a low-cost space hub.

It sounds like space launch is new to New Zealand. What are the main issues addressed, or characteristics of the new body of rocket-related legislation that needed to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine that New Zealand had any rocket launches before Rocket Labs, especially with this quote - "Nobody thought to get into the space industry (before now)".

It sounds like this legislation is setting up the basic framework required to get involved in the space industry. [New Zealand's space agency](http://www.mbie.govt.nz/info-services/sectors-industries/space) was created in April 2016, *after* ground broke on Launch Complex 1.

Comment: I was hoping for something more earth-shattering and ground-breaking, then realized that the creation of a space agency where none existed before certainly counts - thanks!