# Will Scotland require a space agency? Is there one in the works?

Tags: policy, international-politics, government

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21646/12102) to the question *What are the main issues addressed by New Zealand's recent rocket legislation?* says:

> I can't imagine that New Zealand had any rocket launches before Rocket Labs, especially with this quote - "Nobody thought to get into the space industry (before now)".
>
> It sounds like this legislation is setting up the basic framework required to get involved in the space industry. [New Zealand's space agency](http://www.mbie.govt.nz/info-services/sectors-industries/space) was created in April 2016, *after* ground broke on Launch Complex 1.

But [this meta answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1111/12102) to the question *Role of country tags* says:

> Another case might be Scotland, which has a [dedicated rocket launch site](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-highlands-islands-45367640) but no formal space program. You'd need a country tag here to discuss the launch site and/or the regulations placed on it.

**Question:** Will Scotland require a space agency? Is there one in the works?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86382/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-will-scotland-require-a-space-agency-is-there-on).

Comment: Related meta question: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/26446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a [UK Space Agency](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-space-agency) which has a strategy called [LaunchUK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/launch-uk-event) that is pushing for investment in a number of launch sites in the UK.  I guess the Scottish Government may want to create their own agency at some point and have the responsibilites for any launch sites devolved to Holyrood.  There doesn't seem to be any appetite for that at the moment

A bit of background about the Scottish space industry can be found at the [Holyrood magazine website](https://www.holyrood.com/articles/inside-politics/scotland-space-%E2%80%93-spaceports-and-satellite-manufacturing) (as distinct from Holyrood the parliament)

Comment: I hadn't heard of LaunchUK before, thank you for that! You may have read some news or other items that have contributed to the thinking behind your answer. If you can add a link or two that would be great!

Comment: @uhoh I've added a link to a magazine article about Scotland in space, and Wikipedia has a useful page on the UK Space Agency

Comment: Thanks! That's a really interesting article. "Scotland now manufactures more satellites than anywhere outside of the United States..."!